# Mysql Query to calculate Bounce Rate

Tags: mysql, database

We need to calculate how many users bounce in our websites. Given a table that contains the GUID (User-Id), Hostname and Path for each Pageview. If there is only 1 GUID per Hostname then it is considered as bounce.

```
Table Pageviews:
- GUID
- Hostname
- Path
```

I was able to do this query but I think it might be improved. Specially in terms of performance.

```
SELECT 1,  (Bounces / All) * 100 AS `Bounce Rate` From (
SELECT
    count(*) AS All,
    (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT GUID
            FROM pageviews
            GROUP BY GUID
            HAVING count(GUID) = 1
        )
    ) AS Bounces
    FROM pageviews
)
```

Comment: I think your query does not identify bounces correctly. You aren't doing anything with the hostname... Can the same guid not hit multiple hosts?

Comment: Also using count(\*) will recount the same user once per path they hit... If I visit 50 pages I'm still 1 non-bouncing user, not 50. Surely you want count(users that bounced) and count(unique users) calculated per site, *then* sum over all sites and compute your rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Global Bounce Rate

Group the data by guid and hostname (twice, with the latter filtered to give only bounces) then outer join them together :)

```
SELECT count(bounces.guid) `bounces`,
       count(uniqueUsers.guid) `total unique users`,
       count(bounces.guid) / count(uniqueUsers.guid) * 100 `global bounce rate`
FROM (
   SELECT guid, hostname
   FROM PageViews
   GROUP BY guid, hostname
) uniqueUsers
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT guid, hostname
   FROM PageViews
   GROUP BY guid, hostname
   HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
) bounces 
ON uniqueUsers.guid = bounces.guid
AND uniqueUsers.hostname = bounces.hostname
```

Example result:

```
bounces   unique users   global bounce rate
-------   ------------   ------------------
3         6              50.0000
```

Note that all 4 'guid 3' hits against host1 only counts as 1 unique user, but 'guid 1' hits both host1 and host2 so it counts 2 unique users (I think this is the desired logic).

---

## Per Host Bounce Rate

Same but with a group by on the outer query :)

```
SELECT uniqueUsers.hostname,
       count(bounces.guid) bounces,
       count(uniqueUsers.guid) `unique users`,
       count(bounces.guid) / count(uniqueUsers.guid) * 100 `global bounce rate`
FROM (
   SELECT guid, hostname
   FROM PageViews
   GROUP BY guid, hostname
) uniqueUsers
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT guid, hostname
   FROM PageViews
   GROUP BY guid, hostname
   HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
) bounces 
ON uniqueUsers.guid = bounces.guid
AND uniqueUsers.hostname = bounces.hostname
GROUP BY uniqueUsers.hostname;
```

Example result:

```
hostname   bounces   unique users   bounce rate
--------   -------   ------------   -----------
host1      2         4              50.0000
host2      0         1              0.0000
host3      1         1              100.0000
```

---

## Example Data

```
guid   hostname   path
----   --------   ----
1      host1      irrelevant   => bounce 1
2      host1      irrelevant   => bounce 2
3      host1      irrelevant   => non-bounce 1 (visit 1/4)
3      host1      irrelevant
3      host1      irrelevant
3      host1      irrelevant
4      host1      irrelevant   => non-bounce 2 (visit 1/2)
4      host1      irrelevant
1      host2      irrelevant   => non-bounce 3 (visit 1/2)
1      host2      irrelevant
2      host3      irrelevant   => bounce 3
```

Comment: awesome. currently GUID is not shared across hosts but your query gives almost the exact same bounce rate then google analytics. thanks a lot

But may I ask you how you would extend this to have bounce rate per Hostname?

Comment: Done; and I found a cleaner approach using a join.

Comment: I suggest NOT to use JOINs, simply select hostname, sum(Bounce)/count(1) from (select case count(1)  when 1 then 1 else 0 end as Bounce from pageviews group by guid, hostname) group by hostname